# Should I put the attribute in each table even if they are linked to increase performance?

Tags: mysql, schema, database-diagrams

Creating a schema for a workout app, currently building the logs for finished workout sessions.

Here's the part I'm wondering about:

[image]

Wondering if I should put date in each table. The reason is that I want to have one page for workout to date history, one exercise to date for statistics, and then rep to date for weight calculations in upcoming workouts.

Would it be bad practice to put a date in each table even if they are the same? Wouldn't putting the date in only "Rep Log" be bad for performance?

Comment: *Wondering if I should put date in each table.* WHAT date? Each rep refers to a lot of exercises, and each exercise stores its own date - what one date do you want to store in rep log? The same for exercise and workout.

Comment: @Akina The same date in all of them, the date of completion.

Comment: Redundant, over-defined, duplicated data as a way to speed up data processing is quite a common practice. You must find your own balance point between data normalization and denormalization. Denormalization simplifies your queries and improves the performance but increases the disk space consumption and the risk of data inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be bad practice to put a date in each table even if they are the same?

Yes. It puts you at risk for maintaining the data integrity, for example, when the wrong data was entered and needs to be updated. Now you must ensure you update all 3 tables with the correct value, in a transacionally consistent way. You'd essentially always need to use an explicit transaction wrapped around the DML changes (`INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s, and `DELETE`s) of all 3 tables to ensure proper data consistency across them, should an error occur, or should the database or application crash.

Speaking of which, by updating the same data point 3x as often now, and being forced to wrap the changes of all 3 tables in the same transaction, you end up negatively impacting performance because of the increased amount of work, and the increased amount of time the tables will be locked during the writes, which will block other writers (and depending on your isolation level, other readers) to those tables, that could've previously happened concurrently.

> Wouldn't putting the date in only "Rep Log" be bad for performance?

Nope. This is called *premature optimization thinking*. With properly indexed and architected tables, the `JOIN` to get the `date` field from the `Workout Log` table should take a few milliseconds or less, regardless of how big the tables are.

There are a few exception use cases where a denormalized table with pre-calculated data points can improve large scale reporting performance. But that's typically only when you plan to run aggregations that involve most or all of the rows of large transactional tables. Your application use cases don't fall into this category.

---

Follow typical normalization design patterns, and index architecture, and don't worry about prematurely over-optimizing before you have an actual performance problem in front of you. As the solution to said performance problem will be very fact specific to the data as it exists at that point in time. It's not possible to optimize for such a problem before it exists.